# Deployment assembly on GAE/J

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am developing GAE/J application.

As my project become large, I am going to separate my project into several sub project.

I made the top project as Dynamic Web Project as below.

[image]

Then I set deployment assembly as below.

[image]

Then deployed the GAE/J top project from eclipse.

[image]
[image]

But I got `ClassNotFoundException` error.
My understanding is that setting deployment assembly automatically copies the needed jars into WEB-INF/lib folder. But it looks the files are not copied.

**[UPDATE]**
The error message is as below.

```
EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slim3.datastore.DatastoreFilter
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-aa64f63810a8ce7d(Request.java)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:375)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:81)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:460)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:293)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:319)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:311)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:457)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Have you chekced web.xml mapping?

Comment: I have updated my posts. I think this is not web.xml issue.